# How would a previously started Thread within a Service be stopped if said Service is killed by the system and later restarted?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, kill, android-threading

If a `Service` implements a thread, it would hold the reference to it using a class field, so that it could later stop the thread by calling the proper methods (e.g. `quit()` or `quitSafely()` in the case of `HandlerThread`) within `onDestroy()` implementation. My question is, what if the system decides to kill the `Service` and later restarts it, resulting in class fields being reinstantiated and the reference to the original thread being lost? Since `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called, how do we make sure previous threads are stopped before creating a new one?

As answers to other related **Stack Overflow** questions point out, threads are independent from application components' lifecycles. As such, killing of components do not necessarily result in running threads' executions being stopped. Such a situation could result in excess thread creation when components are created and killed repeatedly. What is the best practice for handling such a scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case where `onDestroy()` is not called is when the system is destroying your entire process, so at that point, your entire process's memory is dumped and when it comes back, you'll be in a brand new process. There won't be any cleaning up to do from a previous process that is already gone.

Comment: So as a corollary, can we say that `onDestroy()` is guaranteed to be called as long as the process the service is in is still alive?

Comment: Yes…………………………..